# How redirect to a static page in Public dir in a Symfony5 project

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, heroku, symfony5

I have a simple static website.
On that I build a Symfony project to have an admin panel with easyadmin-bundle and an API to retreive data with ajax on the static page.

The project structure is like this:

- bin/
- config/
- migrations/
- public/

  - css/
  - js/
  - index.html
  - index.php
  - .htaccess
- src/
- templates/

Everythings works fine but I can only access to the page when I call :
*myfakedomain.com/index.html*
The page *myfakedomain.com* is returning a 404 error
What I would like to have is an automatic redirection from *myfakedomain.com/* to *myfakedomain.com/index.html*

I think this can be done ine the .htaccess file. This is the current content of the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This project is deployed on **heroku** so I create a Procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

May it come from that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from your .htacess which redirects all requests to index.php.

Option1 - using Apache (I don't like this method because of side effects)

- Exclude the existing files from the redirection.
- Declare index.html as the default file instead of index.php (when calling .
- Tips: apache-pack can help you. It contains an up-to-date default configuration

Option2 - using Symfony (Recommanded way):

- move index.html to template/index.html
- Create a controller returning a response rendering the template files

```php
# src/Controller/HomeController.php
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(name:'home', '/')]
    public function index (): Response 
    {
        return $this->render('index.html');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
I knew that I could go for the option 2 but I was wondering how can I achieve that with the option 1. Finally I go for the option 2 and it works nicely. The change was small !